# Display two metrics CNTK network?

Tags: cntk

I have a network that has two heads and two distinct outputs that I'd like to view metric/accuracy for individually. Is this possible with CNTK's Trainer class? Right now I have the loss and metric defined as:

```
policyLoss  = cntk.cross_entropy_with_softmax(net.outputs[0], policyVar)
valueLoss   = cntk.cross_entropy_with_softmax(net.outputs[1], valueVar)
loss        = policyLoss + valueLoss

policyError = cntk.element_not(cntk.classification_error(net.outputs[0], policyVar))
valueError  = cntk.element_not(cntk.classification_error(net.outputs[1], valueVar))
#error       = (valueError + policyError) / 2
 error       = valueError # Right now I make due with only viewing valueError for the training data
```

And while this is fine for training, it would be very nice to be able to view the errors separately so as to easily compare them to the validation set errors which I calculate manually with network outputs.

I currently use their built in trainer to train batches likes this:

```
progressPrinter = cntk.logging.ProgressPrinter(tag='Training', num_epochs=maxEpochs)   
trainer         = cntk.Trainer(net, (loss, error), learner, progressPrinter)

for epoch in range(maxEpochs):

    miniBatches = 0
    while miniBatches < gen.stepsPerEpoch:
        X, Y, W = next(g)
        miniBatches += 1 # TODO: NEED to make sure this doesn't go over minibatchSize so we're not inputting more than we're saying we are
        trainer.train_minibatch({net.arguments[0] : X, policyVar : Y, valueVar : W}) 

    trainer.summarize_training_progress()
```

Is there any way to get both metric for the policyVar and metric for the valueVar to display separately? I also calculate validation accuracy manually right now as I want to see it for both the valueVar and the policyVar. Is there a way to do this with CNTK?

Current output:

```
Finished Epoch[1 of 100]: [Training] loss = 3.010285 * 9984, metric = 59.91% * 9984 29.532s (338.1 samples/s);
```

Desired output (or something similar):

```
Finished Epoch[1 of 100]: [Training] loss = 3.010285 * 9984, (policy)metric = 59.91% * 9984 29.532s (338.1 samples/s);
Finished Epoch[1 of 100]: [Training] loss = 3.010285 * 9984, (value )metric = 63.91% * 9984 29.532s (338.1 samples/s);
```